# Understanding the libGDX Projection Matrix

Tags: java, android, camera, libgdx, projection-matrix

Over the past few weeks I've been attempting to learn the libGDX library.  I'm finding it hard, especially for my first endeavor toward game development, to comprehend the system of Camera/viewport relationships.  One line of code that I've been told to use, and the API mentions, is:

```
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

Despite a good 4 hours of research, I'm still lacking a complete understanding of the functionality of this code.  It is to my basic understanding that it "tells" the batch where the camera is looking.  My lack of comprehension is depressing and angering, and I'd appreciate if anyone could assist me.  Another issue with the code snippet is that I'm unsure of when it's necessary to implement (in the render method, create method, etc).

Answer (score 30):

Consider taking a picture with a camera. E.g. using your smartphone camera taking a picture of a bench in the park. When you do that, then you'll see the bench in the park on the screen of your smartphone. This might seem very obvious, but let's look at what this involves.

The location of the bench on the picture is relative to where you were standing when taking the photo. In other words, it is relative to the camera. In a typical game, you don't place object relative to the object. Instead you place them in your game world. Translating between your game world and your camera, is done using a matrix (which is simply a mathematical way to transform coordinates). E.g. when you move the camera to the right, then the bench moves to the left on the photo. This is called the View matrix.

The exact location of the bench on the picture also depends on the distance between bench and the camera. At least, it does in 3D (2D is very similar, so keep reading). When it is further away it is smaller, when it is close to the camera it is bigger. This is called a perspective projection. You could also have an orthographic projection, in which case the size of the object does not change according to the distance to the camera. Either way, the location and size of the bench in the park is translated to the location and size in pixels on the screen. E.g. the bench is two meters wide in the park, while it is 380 pixels on the photo. This is called the projection matrix.

`camera.combined` represents the combined view and projection matrix. In other words: it describes where things in your game world should be rendered onto the screen.

Calling `batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);` instruct the batch to use that combined matrix. You should call that whenever the value changes. This is typically when `resize` is called and also whenever you move or otherwise alter the camera.

If you are uncertain then you can call that in the start of your `render` method.

Answer (score 19):

The other answer is excellent, but I figure a different way of describing it might help it to click.

You generally deal with your game in "world space", a coordinate system that is analogous to the real world. In linear algebra, you can convert points in space from one coordinate system to another by multiplying the point's coordinates by a matrix that represents the relation between two coordinate systems.

The view matrix is multiplied by a point to convert it from world space to camera space (the camera's point of view). The projection matrix is used to convert a point from camera space to screen space (the flat 2D rectangle of your device's screen). When you call `update()` on a camera in Libgdx, it applies your latest changes to position, orientation, viewport size, field of view, etc. to its view and projection matrices so they can be used in shaders.

You rarely need to deal with stuff in camera space in 2D, so SpriteBatch doesn't need separate view and projection matrices. They can be combined into a single matrix that converts straight from world space to screen space, which is already done automatically in the Camera, hence the `camera.combined` matrix.

SpriteBatch has a default built-in shader that multiplies this projection matrix by all the vertices of your sprites so they will be properly mapped to the flat screen.

You should call `setProjectionMatrix` whenever you have moved the camera or resized the screen.

There is a third type of matrix called a model matrix that is used for 3D stuff. A model matrix describes the model's orientation, scale, and position in world space. So it is multiplied by coordinates in the model to move them from local space to world space.

Answer (score 12):

Take for example a basic sidescrolling game.  As the player moves to the side, the camera pans to follow them.  This means that where objects are in the world doesn't necessarily correspond to where they are on the screen, since the screen and the world move relative to each other.

Here's an example: say your screen is 100px*100px square (for some reason).  You place an object at position (50, 0), so it's now in the middle and at the bottom of the screen.  Now say you move your player over to the right, and the whole screen pans to follow the player.  This means that the object you placed earlier should have moved left on the screen.  So it's still at (50, 0) in the world, since it didn't actually move relative to the rest of the scenery, but it should now be drawn at, say, (10, 0) on the screen, since which part of the world the screen is looking at has changed.  This is the difference between "worldspace" (where an object is in the world) and "screenspace" (where the object is drawn on the actual display).

When you try to draw with a `SpriteBatch`, it is by default going to assume worldspace coordinates are the same as screenspace coordinates: when you say "draw at (50, 0)", it's going to draw the object at (50, 0) on the screen.  Even if the camera moves, it's always going to draw at (50, 0) on the screen, so as the camera pans, the object will follow and stay stuck to the same place on the screen.

Since you usually don't want that, you give the `SpriteBatch` a *projection matrix*, which is a transformation matrix that tells how to convert screenspace coordinates to worldspace coordinates, and vice versa.  This way, when you tell the batch "draw at (50, 0)", it can look at the matrix it got from the camera and see that, since the camera has moved, (50, 0) in the world actually means (10, 0) on the screen, and it will draw your sprite in the right place.