# Rotate camera but render sprites so that they appear in their original world positions

Tags: camera, libgdx, rotation, location, sprite

TLDR: I want to rotate camera but render sprites in regards to their world position not camera position.

Howdy,

I'm currently using LibGDX and have come across an issue in regards to camera/object rotation.

Say I have my camera with a rotation of 0 and I have an object(sprite) to the left of the camera's center.

i.e.
[Camera Normal (0 degrees rotation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaik3.png)

The sprite renders fine when given a standard world coordinate, however once I rotate my camera, that world coordinate differs from the camera's new (x, y) values.

If I then rotate my camera smoothly 90 degrees to the right(clockwise so that the up direction is facing to the right like the picture below), the object(sprite) that used to be on the left should have simulated a left rotation in regards to the camera (the rotation happens via the camera, the sprite just needs to update position) and now be below the camera's center point.

i.e.
[Camera Rotated (90 degrees clockwise)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qanDM.png)

I'm confused as to how I would calculate the sprite's new locations/positions during the smooth rotation.

Cheers,
Solist.

Comment: If the camera is rotating/moving, and the object isn't, then the object's world position does not change.

Comment: probably should've referred to the object as a sprite in this situation. The object doesn't move, however the sprite is rendered according to the changing x,y of the camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking everywhere for a solution to this problem for 3 weeks it was merely a matter of me needing to call the method

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

in order to update the sprites to their new position in regards to the changing camera rotation.

This link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703663/understanding-the-libgdx-projection-matrix) explains how the Projection Matrix works.